# Siteminder issue Unable to process SMSESSION cookie

Tags: apache, https, session-cookies, siteminder

The very first time I'm able to logging in into a web page and after that if I click any link its redirecting to login page.

I see the message in the logs as "Unable to process SMSESSION cookie" and there is no error other than this.

All technologies that I used are tagged for the question.

Could any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to fix the problem until to get the proper siteminder package:

Due to the siteminder package update, we got into this issue.

The siteminder setup needs to be changed after a MVN build. Hence MVN build will create a conf files every time.
Also every time you do a maven build, the settings go back to the ‘wrong’ one.

So after every maven build, the following steps must be followed:

Brief Steps:
1. In the web server- remove the redirect at the end
2. In the app server - remove the UAA, 
3. In the app server - remove the context-param (devSecurityContext.xml part)
4. stop and start both web and app server's .

Detailed Steps:

1. Go to the config directory of the web instance and remove the line:
   Redirect 307 /login.fcc 
   From this file config/redirects.conf
2. Go to the web.xml file and remove the UAA filter – i.e. the following lines:

   Remove all the filter configurations.
   `
3. In the same file above the UAA modify the context-param – remove the  devSecurityContext :
   Modify the line:
   /WEB-INF/spring-af.xml,/config/spring/context-*.xml,classpath:/config/spring/context-*.xml,/WEB-INF/devSecurityContext.xml
   To
   /WEB-INF/spring-af.xml,/config/spring/context-*.xml,classpath:/config/spring/context-*.xml